# Is this a grammatically correct sentence?

Tags: grammar

> Me(super angry at him over some matter) : Do not try to talk to me ever. I don't even want to see you.
>
> H(with all innocence and sincerity) : Is it like that time that you want me to talk to you and love you but **you are saying otherwise** OR is it really that you don't want to talk to me?

Quora: [What is the cutest mistake you’ve ever seen someone make?](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-cutest-mistake-you%E2%80%99ve-ever-seen-someone-make/answer/Prakrati-Agarwal-1?srid=uCvw0)

I am confused over "you are saying otherwise".

Comment: Add some more information and also explain the confusion. Such questions will be closed otherwise! They fall under 'unclear you are asking' or 'proofreading'.

Comment: Do you know what "otherwise" means? Or just not in this context? What is your actual problem? Please edit your question with the "Edit" button to make it clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be expressed as:

> H(with all innocence and sincerity) : Is it like that time that you
>   want me to talk to you and love you **but saying otherwise** OR is it
>   really that you don't want to talk to me?

The sentence as it is is also not incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

It cab be modified a little bit as shown below:

> Is it like that time when you want me to talk to you and love you, but you are saying otherwise, OR is it really that you don't want to talk to me?

In the beginning of the sentence "that" is used twice, so try replacing it with "when", which is more accurate in this context. I have also added punctuation wherever necessary. Hope it helps.